# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address

Tags: axis, webservice-client, http-status-code-401, reportserver

Getting below exception when calling ReportServer webservice fom Websphere 7.0.

The webservice call works when I put all the required JAXWS2.2.7 - jaxws-ri jars under classes directory of the profile.

It is not working when I create shared libraries and put those jars. It is strange for me because all the applications functions were working except this Microsoft ReportServer webservice call.

I went through stackoverflow and googled and found various reason but I could not narrow down to my issue as it is working when I put it in classes directory of websphere profile.

**Exception:**

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address : http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address : http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx

Any information on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late but if you are calling a Windows service that requires some sort of authentication - often NTLM or Kerberos in an enterprise, your Unix caller isn't providing the necessary credentials.